# Truth values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, series

Can someone explain to me why parentheses are necessary for boolean comparisons in pandas? Let me set up an MWE.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["blue", 10], ["orange", 3], ["green", 7], ["red", 5]], columns = ["color", "score"])
```

The resulting dataframe:

```
    color  score
0    blue     10
1  orange      3
2   green      7
3     red      5
```

Now, I would like to compare some truth values. I can run

```
(df.score>=5) == (df.score>=5)
```

which gives, as expected,

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
```

However, if I instead run

```
df.score>=5 == df.score>=5
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1534, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is it about the parentheses that makes the comparison possible?

Comment: Remember that Python has [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html#comparisons): `df.score>=5 == df.score>=5` is parsed as `(df.score >= 5) and (5 == df.score) and (df.score >= 5)`

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. The == was now comparing two series of booleans, but rather checking whether a series was equal to 5, which is nonsense. Since comparisons are in general non-associative, the parentheses are necessary to clarify things, and this is a general Python fact and not specific to pandas.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to examine a simpler expression.
Comparing score to `5` gives a `Series` of booleans, great.
What if we throw in a boolean constant?

```
df.score >= 5 == True
```

Right, it's ambiguous, consider using .any() or .all().

Now, why does python even support that in the first place?
It mirrors the notation you'll find in any math text.
A compact expression like this can be quite useful:

```
if low <= 2 * value < high:
```

and pandas, with its operator overrides,
is leveraging such support.

You can also write `if a == b == c == d == e:`,
but that comes up much less often.